# Keyword search returns wrong description of videos in YouTube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, keyword-search

The videos returned by Youtube API do not contain the search keywords. In fact, the videos do not have any description when you open the URL.

For example this was video was retrieved using the keyword `parachuteadvansed`:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?hl=en-GB&v=Gqe4td6xpjQ
```

Description of the video:

- -026. Watch Later Anushka sharma childhood imagesby iram nadeemFeatured 117 ·
- -213. Watch Later Anushka Sharma Shine
  Stories 3 Film Dealby parachuteadvansed 472 views ·
- -136. Watch Later
  Anushka Sharma Shine    Stories Prasad Bidappa Fashion Showby
  parachuteadvansed 956 views ·
- -135. Watch Later Deep Conditioning in 20 Minutes Parachute Advansed Deep Conditioning Hot Oilby parachuteadvansed 9236 views ·
- -129. Watch Later Anushka Sharma Shine Stories School Daysby ..."

This description are actually the titles of the additional videos that are displayed on the right hand side of the page.

I used this **query**:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=50&q=parachuteadvansed&orderby=published&v=2
```

I have received 2000+ videos like this over the past week while fetching for numerous keywords. I am using YouTube’s Java API and I did not face this problem until last week. This does not occur for every fetch, but over the day I receive an average of 300 URLs with such description.

The problem is that when you fetch for the keywords again, the video is not returned. So, this issue cannot be replicated. Also, if you fetch the video separately, the video does not contain a description.

If this continues, then there will be a lot of irrelevant data coming from YouTube.

I would like to know if anyone is facing the same issue or if someone know what is going wrong in my query.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. What I think is happening is that if a video has no description, the titles of the related videos are returned as the description and included in the search. I have noticed this in both version 2 and version 3 of the Youtube api. And yes, this causes all kinds of videos returned in a search that should not be.

Comment: I guess the videos with such kind of description need to be recrawled again so that the description is replaced with null. I have noticed that the description obtained contains a pattern like "&middot;" and "<b>..</b>" in the description string.

Answer (score 0):

***Update**: The underlying issue has been identified, and the incorrect descriptions should no longer be returned once the fix is deployed and the search index is refreshed.*

There's nothing different that you could be doing to work around this; the description in the search feed is being incorrectly populated due to a bug in the YouTube search index.

I'll report it internally.

(In the future, please follow the advice in [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html) and use the YouTube API issue tracker to [report buggy behavior](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29).)